# Python- how to create new dictionary based on comparison of list of values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have below dictionary list and list of values which need to compare each to derive a new dictionary

```
constent_keys=['name','desig','salary','status']
dict_list=[{'name':'abc', 'desig':['account','market'], 'salary':['10000','5000']},
           {'name':'bsc', 'desig':['sales','anaysis'], 'salary':['5000','2200'], 'status':'True'}]
```

As seen above, the 'status' is the optional in the dict_list payload.
Now i need to compare as follows with below sudo code

```
for item in dict_list:
    if key from 'constent_keys_list' in item  and item.values are type(list):
       new_dict= derive/split new dictionary based on length of list_of_values
```

#Expected:
The length of dict_list initially was 2 and
after deriving/splitting based on length of values it should be 4 in this case.
here 'abc' and 'bsc' have to derive new dictionary as it held different 'desig' and status could be optional

```
dict_list=[{'name':'abc', 'desig':'account', 'salary':'10000'},
           {'name':'abc', 'desig':'market', 'salary':'5000'},
           {'name':'bsc', 'desig':'sales', 'salary':'5000', 'status':'True'},
           {'name':'bsc', 'desig':'anaysis', 'salary':'2200'}
```

The result should derive new dictionary based on the values list

Appreciated if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some clarity to the pseudo code. Your original dict list has 2 dicts and your expected dict list has 4 and based on your current pseudo code, I cannot comprehend how that would be possible.

Comment: I agree with Deepak

Comment: why is status only on the bsc/sales/5000 target? and not also on bsc/anaysis/2200 ? and should that be analisys=?

Comment: @Deepak and Sujya, i have updated the question. ideally if the same person held differnt desig, this has to be splited based on desig.. hope you understood the use case.. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickArtner 'status' is the optional , it may come or not

Comment: WHY is `status` from `{'name':'bsc', 'desig':['sales','anaysis'], 'salary':['5000','2200'], 'status':'True'}`  only applied to _one_ of the resultings and not the other?

Comment: Yes @PatrickArtner the status applicable to one of the results and not other

Comment: Why one and nto the other. Moonphase?Daytime? There must be some rule to this - you do not give any.

Comment: @PatrickArtner this is the expected behavior and as it said the value set only if  flag  == 'True' or else it wont set any value..

Comment: You convert a list from `{'name':'bsc', 'desig':['sales','anaysis'], 'salary':['5000','2200'], 'status':'True'}` which _Expands_ to two target entries - BOTH of them have the `status: True` to begin with but you only apply it to _ONE_ after expansion. For that to happen you need to give a _rule_

Answer (score 0):

You can deconstruct your `dict_list`, use "zip" to create matching tuples for the index-based order of the `"desig"`/`"salary"` values and create a new resulting dict like so:

```
dict_list=[{'name':'abc', 'desig':['account','market'], 'salary':['10000','5000']},
           {'name':'bsc', 'desig':['sales','anaysis'], 'salary':['5000','2200'], 
            'status':'True'}]

target = []

for d in dict_list:
    nam = d["name"]
    des = d["desig"]
    # zip only zips up to the lower list length - but yours are same length so it is ok
    tups = zip(d["desig"], d["salary"])  

    for des,sal in tups:
        target.append({"name":nam, "desig":des, "desig":des, "salary":sal})
        if "status" in d:
            target[-1]["status"] = d["status"]

print(target)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'abc', 'desig': 'account', 'salary': '10000'}, 
 {'name': 'abc', 'desig': 'market', 'salary': '5000'}, 
 {'name': 'bsc', 'desig': 'sales', 'salary': '5000', 'status': 'True'}, 
 {'name': 'bsc', 'desig': 'anaysis', 'salary': '2200', 'status': 'True'}]
```

You do not give any rule for why `"status"` is only in one of your resulting dicts - to apply `"status"` only to the first expanded dict one you can do:

```
# apply "status" only to first desig
for i, (des,sal) in enumerate(tups): 
    target.append({"name":nam, "desig":des, "desig":des, "salary":sal})
    if not i and "status" in d:
        target[-1]["status"] = d["status"]
```

to get:

```
[{'name': 'abc', 'desig': 'account', 'salary': '10000'}, 
 {'name': 'abc', 'desig': 'market', 'salary': '5000'}, 
 {'name': 'bsc', 'desig': 'sales', 'salary': '5000', 'status': 'True'}, 
 {'name': 'bsc', 'desig': 'anaysis', 'salary': '2200'}]
```